# How to visualize and export player generated parts of a Minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I build a few structure in different worlds which I'd now like to put into one single common world. Is there a way do this, preferably without having to manually select which parts of each world are hand-made?

Comment: I'd love to see a Minecraft diff tool (like James [commented](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52566/how-to-visualize-and-export-player-generated-parts-of-a-minecraft-world#comment76483_52568)). Throwing in another 200 rep if you write and open source it yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used MCEdit to do the same task as you.  I'm pretty sure block-selection is the only way to do it right now, and in most cases you really have to deal with the terrain anyway if you are like me.  I built a castle into a desert mountain, and that was hell to move, but I needed the terrain or else it wouldn't make sense.

One thing you might try as I did is to cut the chunk(s) the building onto MCEdit's clipboard, create a new empty world, paste the clipboard, erase the extra terrain blocks around the building, and then paste the result into new location (with air blocks ignored of course).

Finding the diff between a generated world and what you've built wouldn't be that hard ... sounds like an excellent project :)

Comment: yes, I guess I'll have to do this chunk-wise. Maybe there's at least a tool to smooth the terrain transitions afterwards...

Comment: ok, I did it this way - I deleted all chunks but the ones I wanted, and then pasted these remaining chunks in my other world

Answer (score 5):

There is an mod for Minecraft called [World Edit](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit) that has a nice Copy/Paste ability that includes sending it to and receiving it from a file.. Can find the wiki page on doing it [here](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Clipboard).

Comment: I know WorldEdit, but does it allow me to select only blocks that players modified and ignores those created by terrain generation?

Comment: @Zommuter I think you just mark the environment and it takes anything. If you are looking for something automated like a Diff program that takes the see, sees what the world would create and then records all the blocks that are not at their default settings, then no.. and to my knowledge no one has made that as of yet (though I have clearly thought about it a few times :))

Comment: I meant 'the seed' not 'the see' but its past edit time.

Comment: yes, something like `git` for Minecraft :-7 oh well, then it will be not-so-nice biome transitions in my showcase world...

Comment: I finally used MCEdit, so I unaccepted your answer... However, since you mentioned the Diff program you get the bounty :-7

Comment: @Zommuter Happy Editing :)